# Value shifting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a variable which is `@a = 000000`, next value will be multiple of 5.

So, next value should be `000005`.

Next value after that will be `000010` and so on until `999995`.

Once it reaches highest values it should error out. Length might get differ it can 00 or 0000000. Length gets differ all time.

I tried using bit wise operator but it doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer on my own.

declare @value varchar(100),@Next_Value int 
set @value = '000000' 
set @Next_Value = 5 
select RIGHT( POWER(10, LEN(@value))+ @Next_Value ,LEN(@value))